# Clone not working as intended

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code should in my mind make a clone of the element #loaded_start_container and put the clone into #content-wrapper with all its children.

This however  creates a clone, but none of the children. If I just move the element without cloning, it works.

```
var loaded_content = $('#loaded_start_container').clone().attr('id', 'content_start');
$('#content-wrapper').html(loaded_content);
```

JQuery 2.0.3

**Edit. Added entire Js**

```
$(function(){
    var time_before_load = new Date().getTime();
    loadContent('start', function(){
        console.log('Now start IS loaded. Evidence ');
        console.log($('#loaded_start_container'));
        changeContent('start');
        loadContent('projects', function(){
            loadContent('about', function(){
                  console.log('All content has been loaded. It took '+ (new Date().getTime() - time_before_load) + ' miliseconds');
            });
        });
    });

    $('nav ul li').bind('click', function(){
        $('.active_content').removeClass('active_content');
        var clicked = $(this).addClass('active_content').attr('id');
        changeContent(clicked);
    });

});


changeContent = function(source) {
    console.log('Changed to ' + source);
    var loaded_content = $('#loaded_'+source+'_container').clone().attr('id', 'content_'+source);
    $('#content-wrapper').html(loaded_content);
};
loadContent = function(source, callback) {
    $('#loaded_'+source+'_container').load(source + '.html', callback());
};
```

Comment: Hopefully just a typo in your copy/paste but `'content_start` => `'content_start'`  (missing your closing quote).

Comment: $('#content-wrapper').append(loaded_content); will do

Comment: SenorAmor, yes that's a typo :)
append won't solve the problem. And I don't want to append, I want to replace the current content

Comment: So are you trying to clone `$('#loaded_start_container')` and change the existing id to `content_start`?

Comment: Yes, I figured I need to change the id since else I would have 2 identical id's. I am not changing the existing id, but the clone's

Comment: This is what happens when you mess with the natural order of things.

Answer (score 2):

**This will do it:**

```
var loaded_content = $('#loaded_start_container').clone().attr('id', 'content_start');
$('#content-wrapper').append(loaded_content );
```

**Fiddle Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/88SLA/4/

`.html()` works .. but replaces existing content. See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/88SLA/5/

Comment: Hmm, weird. It does not work when I implement it. It still only clones the parent but excludes the children